# Gstreamer ONVIF - adding metadata to stream

Tags: python, docker, gstreamer, onvif

I'm trying to implement server which would be seen as something like ONVIF Profile M - analytical device. As for now, most of endpoints are implemented in such way that Onvif Device Manager can communicate with my server successfully, but problems have risen once I started implementing streaming capabilites and metadata.

As for my understanding, it should work more or less in a way that:

1. ODM (or any client of my device) at some points sends GetStreamURI request
2. Server responds with URI of RTSP server
3. Client sends RTSP request OPTION
4. Server responds with list of available options
5. Client sends RTSP request DESCRIBE
6. Server responds with proper SDP which contains list of available endpoints (video, audio, metadata) along with Payload Type for each source.
7. Based on what client is looking for, it sends SETUP request to the right endpoint, depending on protocol it also sends ports on which expects the streams to be provided.

I was trying to implement RTSP server using Gstreamer, however I'm not sure how should I handle some of the points I mentioned above:

I can easily create RTSP Server that streams video, as I can also setup UDP stream that streams some text metadata, but I cannot send text metadata (for example bounding boxes) over RTSP. No matter how I try to allign pipelines there is always something wrong with decoding payload type or negotiating capabilites between components of pipeline.

I'm having a hard time understanding how I should handle DESCRIBE request: as in ODM it is sent on base endpoint (rtsp://address:port), but rest of the request is send based on content of SDP. As for Gstreamer RSTPServer - it has mountpoints set to RTSPMediaFactory which in my understanding shall implement particular streams in own endpoints(/video, /metadata in my example). But it seems that gstreamer's RTSPServer itself cannot respond on DESCRIBE request as this functionality is handled in each of RTSPMediaFactory. I also cannot edit SDP that's being generated based on created pipeline. Is it possible to implement such RTSP server that has synchronized /metadata and /video on separate endpoints, which are definied on some main endpoint?

I recently discovered that there is a gst-rst-plugins package that contains some ONVIF functionality, such as onvifmetadatacombiner - is it possible to implement what I need using this aggregator? How shall such pipeline look like? I couldn't find any example of usage of gst-rst-onvif plugins.

My other question related to this topic is: I need to wrap this server inside docker container. How can I handle port mapping, since when I run container I don't know yet which port will be requested by client? And publishing all ports (which I'm aware is generally very bad practice) won't solve the problem, as they'll be mapped randomly.